# Problems while installing pg gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pg

I need to install pg gem, but the installation failed. I've tried all the solution propesed in other questions but no luck.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/TiCugXVP) is my output, and [here](http://pastebin.com/3UqAUfFQ) is my "mkmf.log" file

Any idea?

**[UPDATE]**

I've solved the first problem by putting libs in the correct directory. But now I've another problem:

```
find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- yes

--------------------

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2 -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-1.9.1-static  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */
```

**[UPDATE2]**

Solved it by putting links to "libgcc", "libgcc_s", "crtend.o", "crtendS.o", "crtbeginS.o" and "crtbegin.o" into /usr/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing development libraries even for glibc. Just install devel packages for glibc and postgresql and try again.

Comment: @Trenza It looks like base header files are not found in standard directories. Does exist `/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h` ? glibc devel package should place it there.

Comment: No! sys dir doesn't exist. I've found it in /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h